# Diferenciar los días de vacaciones repartidos entre dos años laborales

Tags: php, algoritmos

Tengo una aplicación para que cada usuario de una empresa pueda seleccionar sus vacaciones. Los tipos de usuarios son ***fijos*** y ***temporales***.

Los usuarios ***fijos*** tienen en total ***24 días de vacaciones al año*** y los ***temporales*** tienen ***2 días por mes trabajado***, siendo acumulables.

Mi problema viene con los usuarios temporales. Tengo una función que me devuelve la diferencia de meses que hay desde que un empleado temporal entró a la empresa hasta hoy.

```
function difmeses($fechaingreso){

    $fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso);

    $fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);

    $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

    $meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;

    return $meses;
}
```

Con esta función y operaciones le voy añadiendo a los usuarios temporales 2 días por mes trabajado.

Mi problema es: ¿cómo puedo hacer que la función me diferencie entre días de 2018 y días de 2019?.

Me explico:

***Usuario1*** entró en la empresa el 25/01/2018, entonces hasta el 25/12/2018 tendría 22 días. Hasta el 25/01/2019 tendría 24. Quiero diferenciar entre los 22 días de 2018 y los 2 días de 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es comprobar si el año de entrada es distinto al de salida. 
En ese caso yo haría lo siguiente:

**- Primero, calculo los meses del primer año:**

- Si entra el 1 de Junio hacemos (12-6)+1 que multiplicado por 2 tienes los días del año de entrada. El 12 son los meses del año, restando el mes de entrada (en este caso
  Junio) nos da los meses que faltan para terminar el año. Le sumo +1
  por hay que contar también el propio Junio sino, en caso de que
  entrara el 1 de Diciembre, obtendríamos 0.

**- Segundo, calculo los meses del año de salida;**

- Esto es tan sencillo como recuperar el mes de salida y restarle 1. Esto se debe a que el mes en el que se va, no trabaja.

Aplicando este pseudocódigo:

**ENTRADA:** 1-03-2018

**SALIDA:**  1-06-2019

```
(12-3) + 1 = 10 meses * 2 = 20 días de vacaciones de 2018

        6-1 = 5 meses * 2 = 10 días de vacaciones de 2019
```

En total son 30 días de vacaciones.

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Pues tendrías que controlar el año de $fechaingreso y el de $fechaactual.
Si es el mismo no pasa nada, pero si es distinto tienes que hacer dos $fechaingreso y $fechaactual.

Es decir, $fechaingreso y $fechafinalaño sería la primera parte (los 22 días) y $fechainicioañoactual y $fechaactual sería la segunda parte (los 2 dias).

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve este code.

```
function difmeses($fechaIngreso, $fechaActual){

    //convertimos en DateTime las dos fechas a calcular
    $fechaInicial = new DateTime($fechaIngreso);
    $fechaFinal = new DateTime($fechaActual);

    //obtenemos la diferencia de años
    $anioInicial = $fechaInicial->format('Y');
    $anioFinal = $fechaFinal->format('Y');

    //hacemos un ciclo para cada año
    $i = 1;
    while ($anioInicial <= $anioFinal) {
        $nextAnio = $anioInicial + 1;//calculamos el año siguiente
        $nextAnio = new DateTime($nextAnio.'-01-01');//lo convertimos en obj DateTime

        //si es el ultimo año a calcular el calculo es contra la fecha actual
        if ($anioInicial == $anioFinal) {
            $diferencia = $fechaInicial->diff($fechaFinal);//diferencia
            $meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;//sacamos los meses
            echo $meses.' - '.$anioInicial;//imprimimos o guardamos en un array
            echo '<br>';
        } else {//si no es contra el año siguiente
            $diferencia = $fechaInicial->diff($nextAnio);
            $meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;
            echo $meses.' - '.$anioInicial;
            echo '<br>';
        }

        //reajustamos variables
        $fechaInicial = $nextAnio;
        $anioInicial++;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Demo

```
echo difmeses('2017-10-01', '2019-05-21');
echo difmeses('2017-10-01', '2018-12-01');
echo difmeses('2017-10-01', '2017-12-01');

3 - 2017
12 - 2018
4 - 2019

3 - 2017
11 - 2018

2 - 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Te añado el código necesario para hacer lo que quieres. Quizá no sea lo más óptimo, pero funciona. Lo único que ahora en el retorno, en vez devolver un número entero, devuelve un array de esta manera:

```
Array
(
  [2016] => 4
  [2017] => 12
  [2018] => 12
  [2019] => 0
)
```

Código:

```
$fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso); //ejemplo: 2016-08-01
$anioInicio = (int)$fechainicial->format("Y");

$fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);
$anioFinal = (int)$fechafinal->format("Y");

if ($anioInicio != $anioFinal){
    for($i = $anioInicio; $i<= $anioFinal; $i++){
        if($i == $anioInicio){
            $yearEnd =  new DateTime($i."-12-31"); 
            $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($yearEnd);
            $meses[$i] = $diferencia->m;
        }elseif($i == $anioFinal){
            $yearStart =  new DateTime($i."-01-01"); 
            $diferencia = $yearStart->diff($fechafinal);
            $meses[$i] = $diferencia->m;
        }else{
            $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);
            $meses[$i] = 12;
        }
    }
}else{
    $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);
    $meses[$anioFinal] = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;
}
```